# WooCommerce not saving post meta value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, post-meta

In my WooCommerce site i have create a product and in this product i have attached a lot of pdf files so that after user buy it he can download all these pdf files but the problem is that in this product i have more than 375 files so after added 320 files its working fine and when i add 319 product and hit update button page updated successfully but the 321th products is removed i thought it was some mistake so i added it back and same thing happen i don't know why i just enable the debug log

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

but noting log no error just removed the 321th record can anyone please tell me is there any limit of woocommerce or anything else o this problem can be resolved

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is probably happening because you must be passing input limits on the form submit. To solve this you will need to open php.ini from your server and increase the **max_input_vars** variable which will probably be **1000** to **2000**.

This happens because for each field you generate woocommerce must be generating one or two more. what goes over the edge. so just increase it and **restart** that will solve.

Some hosts will not let you modify or increase **php.ini** in which case you should contact the host and request the increase.